# Why docker-compose containers cannot be reach?

Tags: docker

I have installed images on aws(t2.micro),
have the following docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
 eureka:
  image: voipp/eurekaserver
  ports:
  - "8888:8888"
configserver:
 image: voipp/configserver
 ports:
   - "8761:8761"
```

I have all images installed on a server, and call *docker-compose up*.
Docker starts my containers, but I cannot reach them from my PC!

Help me figure it out, plz.

PS. When I start images just by command *docker run -p ...* everything works fine(apps are approacheable), but docker-compose doesn't work as expected(

UPD: ports are opened in aws, how else i can reach em simply after *docker run -p...*

UPD2: If i start my app without container, it really is able to reach outer 8761 port

Comment: Did you open up AWS security groups on those ports, 8888 & 8761?

Comment: @kosa yeah, because i can reach em after *docker run -p...*

Comment: @kosa the problem somehow related to container.
My app, stated inside container cannot reach outer 8761 port.
But, when i start app without container, it really able to reach outer 8761 port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the container calls on its inner localhost, not remote containers .